# Angular: Displaying Space between primitive elements of an array in the templete

Tags: angular

I'm displaying a nested JSON object in a table which has array of strings like obj.someKey = ['a','b','c']. In the td tag of the table I'm directly displaying the array content.

```
<td> {{obj.someKey}}</td>
```

What I'm trying is I want to have a space after each element in the UI. I cannot use *ngFor since loop will display the elements in multiple td tags. Is there a way to have a space after comma each elements of the array?

Comment: How about *ngFor with spans?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use like follow, If that meet your requirements

```
<td> {{ obj.someKey.join(" ") }} </td>
```

Comment: I believe better approach is to calculate `obj.someKey.join(" ")` in *.ts* file and store in variable; just print that variable in front-end!